# Django: Model.objects.filter() returns an empty Queryset

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am using Django for the Backend in my webapplication. I have a some data in my database which I can query just fine with the objects.get() method.

```
 volumes = Volume.objects.get(volumeEngTitle="If there is a volume Title")
```

This returns the following value in Postman:

```
{
    "volumeNumber": 8.1
    "chapterNumber": 12
    "Translated": True
}
```

But I need to return multiple volumes that have the same title. This is why I tried to use filter() but the result of the Http.Get in Postman is always an empty set, e.g {}. filter() seems to never find any instance that matches the volumeEngTitle even though it exists.

Here is the whole function to return the volume.

```
from rest_framework.response import Response
from .serializers import VolumeSerializer
from ..volumeModel import Volume

@api_view(['GET'])
def getVolume(request):

    volumes = Volume.objects.filter(volumeEngTitle="If there is a volume Title")
    #This works like a charm but only for a single instance:
    #volumes = Volume.objects.get(volumeEngTitle="If there is a volume Title")
    serializer = VolumeSerializer(volumes)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

The result of this method is always {}. Even though it works fine with the get() method.
I understand that get() is for a single return value and filter() gives me a queryset with mulitple values. But I can't figure out why filter doesn't return anything at all.
Do I need to specify anything for filter()?

EDIT:
The VolumeSerializer looks like this:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from ..volumeModel import Volume

class VolumeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Volume
        fields = ['mangaVolumeNumber', 'chapterNumber', 'Translated']
```

Comment: What does your serializer look like?

Comment: Add to the serializer many=True if you want more than one entries

Comment: I have edited the post to include the VolumeSerializer.

Comment: + print volumes under the filter what is it returning?

Comment: It was the many=True that fixed the problem. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add `many=True` to your Serializer:

```
serializer = VolumeSerializer(volumes, many=True)
```

The `Serializer.__init__` method expects a model instance, not a queryset.

Comment: That fixed the problem, Thank you! I have just never seen it but it makes sense now.